# Problems IP-messagin and Twilio

Tags: javascript, node.js, twilio

I am using Twilio for the IP messaging. I want to create a chat in my mobile hybrid app, and I am trying to get the whatsup style, with delivered and read messages status.
After the initial excitement for the Twilio library, right now nothing is working :(.  The chat works the 40% of times, the other times I get several errors. Before looking at the errors, I want to explain how I structured the code.

The idea is to ask, once logged, all the channels of that user and store them in `self.channels`, so I can visualize the last conversations of that user.

1) The very first step is asks a token as soon as a user logs to my app.

```
 setChatToken = function()
{
 _token = data.token;
 var accessManager = new Twilio.AccessManager(_token);
 _messagingClient = new Twilio.IPMessaging.Client(accessManager);
 _messagingClient.on('channelUpdated', function(channel) 
    {
     for ( c in self.channels)
        {
         if (self.channels[c].sid == channel.sid)
            { self.channels[c] = channels; }
        }
     });
// return a promise;
}
```

2) Then I ask all the channels

```
// init chat system
     setChatToken()  
        .then(function()
                {       
                 // Listen for new invitations to your Client
                 _messagingClient.on('channelInvited', function(channel) 
                    {
                     // Automatically join channels that you were invited to
                     channel.join().then(function(channel)
                        {
                         handleMessageEvents(channel);
                         channel.attributes['him']  = channel['createdBy'];
                         // I'll separate old, recent and new msgs
                         channel['recent-messages'] = [];
                         channel['new-messages']    = [];                        
                         self.last_channels.push(channel);
                        });
                    }); 

                  // asks all the channels
                 getChannels()
                    .then(function()
                            { // chat init ready
                              self.ready = true;
                            });
                }
             )
        .catch(function(err){console.error(err);});
```

3) this is the code for asking all the channels. I check if there are new messages looking at the `channel.lastConsumedMessageIndex`. I consider last 7 messages as 'recent', the other as 'old'.

```
var getChannels = function()
        {   
         // Get Messages for previously created channels
         _messagingClient.getChannels()
            .then(function(channels) 
              { // GET CHANNELS
               for (i in channels) 
                 {  
                  var channel = channels[i];
                  channel['recent-messages'] = [];  
                  channel['old-messages']    = [];                    
                  channel['new-messages']    = [];  
                  handleMessageEvents(channel);                               
                  self.last_channels.push(channel);
                 }
               })
            .then(function()
               {  // GET MEMBERS
                var promises_update_read_index = [];                   
                for (i in self.last_channels)
                   {
                    var channel = self.last_channels[i];
                    var promise = 
                        channel.getMembers()
                            .then(function(channelMembers)
                                    {
  // check the last message read from  the other user, to know
  // if there are new messages not read
                                     for(m in channelMembers)
                                       {
                                        var member = channelMembers[m];
                                        if (member.identity != me.id)
                                            { 
                                              channel.attributes['him'] = member.identity;
                                              channel.attributes['hisLastMsgIndex'] = member.lastConsumedMessageIndex;

                                              // last message consumed update
                                              member.on('updated', function(updatedMember) 
                                                {
                                                   //handle the read status information for this member
                                                   updateHisMessageReadStatus(updatedMember.identity, 
                                                                              updatedMember.lastConsumedMessageIndex, 
                                                                              updatedMember.channel.sid);
                                                 });                                                                                        
                                            }
                                        else
                                            { // it's me
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                 );
                      promises_update_read_index.push(promise);
                    }
                   return $q.all(promises_update_read_index);
                })          
            .then(function()
                { //GET MESSAGES
                  var promises_update_messages = [];                   
                  for (i in self.last_channels)
                    {
                     var channel = self.last_channels[i];
                     //determine the newest message index
                     var areThereNewMsgs = false;
                     var lastConsumedMessageIndex = channel.lastConsumedMessageIndex;
         // consider the last 7 messages as 'recent', the other as 'old'
                     var promise = 
                         channel.getMessages(7)
                            .then(function(lastChannelMessages)
                              {
                               for (j in lastChannelMessages)
                                 {
                                  var message = lastChannelMessages[j];
                                  if (
                                      message.author != me.id &&
                                      message.index > lastConsumedMessageIndex
                                      )
                                    { // there are new messages
                                     var hisId = channel.attributes['him'];
                                     channel['new-messages'].push(message);
                                    }
                                   else
                                    { 
                                     if ( channel.attributes['hisLastMsgIndex']
                                                      < channel.lastConsumedMessageIndex 
                                                    )
                                                    { message['msg-read'] = false;}
                                                 else
                                                    { message['msg-read'] = true; }
                                                 channel['old-messages'].push(message); 
                                                }
                                             if (message.author != me.id)
                                                    { message['msg-read'] = false; } //hide for him                                                                         
                                             }
                                        });
                        promises_update_messages.push(promise);                             
                    }
                 return $q.all(promises_update_messages);
                })
            .catch(function(err){console.error('getMessages '+JSON.stringify(err));})
            .then(function()
                    {   
                     $rootScope.$broadcast(self.CHANNEL_UPDATE_EVENT);                      
                     deferred.resolve(true); // i'm ready
                    })
            .catch(function(err)
                    {
                     console.error(err);
                     deferred.reject(err);
                    });
         return deferred.promise;
        }
```

One problem is that often, when I create a channel, the other user doesn't automatically join the channel, so I send messages that are never delivered.
Another problem is

```
 getMembers {"status":403,"description":"Forbidden","body":{"message":"Access forbidden","status":403}}
```

when I invoke getChannels() as defined before.

Is there any tutorial to build a full chat like this? Or, do you have suggestion on what to modify and how to check the problems'

Thank yo

Answer (score 0):

When doing a `getChannels()`, you're receiving all channels, which are known to the client. 
Though you have no permissions to get members and messages from a channels you're not joined to.
Thus you might want to change your code to:

```
_messagingClient.getChannels()
  .then(channels => channels
     .filter(channel => channel.status === 'joined'))
     .forEach(channel => {
       channel.getMembers();
       channel.getMessages();
       etc...
     })
  );
```

Comment: oooh I see... thank you. I also see that, after a while, Twilio get an error about the socket connection... I think it's something about the timeout after inactivity. After that error, the user is no more capable to receive message. Is there a way to keep the connection alive?  Thank you

Comment: You don't need to do anything - connection should be kept alive by itself. It may be a library bug. Which version are you using?